# How to create and retrieve class object from a list

Tags: python, python-3.4

I have an xml of following type:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RootNode>
<childElem>
<prop1 type="int">1</prop1>
<prop2 type="int">2</prop2>
</childelem>
<childElem>
<prop1 type="int">3</prop1>
<prop2 type="int">4</prop2>
</childelem>
<childElem>
<prop1 type="int">5</prop1>
<prop2 type="int">6</prop2>
</childelem>
<childElem>
<prop1 type="int">7</prop1>
<prop2 type="int">8</prop2>
</childelem>
</RootNode>
```

I have defined class  to store all child elements as different instance of the class.
I am trying to append the objects in a list and then retrieving.

in this xml there are total 4 childelem.
I have printed the properties of each object after creating each object.
There I am seeing each object has different property values.

But after that when I am trying to retrieve each object from the list in a for loop and printing properties of each retrieved object, it's printing last childelem object four times.

Here is the code snippet

```
def getObjects(self,xmlStr,elem):
    objList = []
    root = ET.fromstring(xmlStr)
    rootNode = root.find(elem)
    for obj in rootNode.findall('childElem'):
        myObj = Obj()
        for props in obj:
            myObj.populate(props.tag,props.text)
        print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")
        print(myObj.getProps())
        print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")
        objList.append(myObj)

    for obj1 in objList:
        print(obj1.getProps())
        print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")
    return objList
class Obj:
    properties = {}

    def populate(self,name,value):
        self.properties[name] = value
    def getProps(self)
        return self.properties
```

I am new to Python, can some one explain what is wrong?
Why in the retrieval for loop only last childElem is coming four times?
How can I rectify the error?

here is the out put

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
{'prop1': '1', 'prop2': '2'}
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
{'prop1': '3', 'prop2': '4'}
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
{'prop1': '5', 'prop2': '6'}
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
{'prop1': '7', 'prop2': '8'}
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
{'prop1': '7', 'prop2': '8'}
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
{'prop1': '7', 'prop2': '8'}
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
{'prop1': '7', 'prop2': '8'}
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
{'prop1': '7', 'prop2': '8'}
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Comment: can you please post the code for the populate and getProps methods here?

Comment: Can you show the output?

Comment: added the code for populate and getProps
also added the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sharing a mutable dictionary on the class between the different instances of `Obj`. If you change it to be an instance variable (by setting `self.properties` in `Obj.__init__`), the code should work as you'd like:

```
class Obj:

    def __init__(self):
        self.properties = {}

    # The rest of Obj's methods.
```

As it stands, your code creates one dictionary, `Obj.properties` (which is still accessible via `self.properties` on an instance). Then the `myObj.populate` calls each update that one dictionary, so the details for the last element are printed 4 times.